# Login to Android WebView using browser cookies

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I'm using Java code on an Android app to login and I receive cookies after I successfully login (using Retrofit).

What I want to do is if the login is successful and I go to a different tab which has a WebView that I'm automatically logged in with my browser cookie. On iOS this works perfectly. On Android I think I have to change something in my code so I'm using the following code to set the cookies in my `CookieManager`:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

for(String cookie: response.headers().values("Set-Cookie")){
    System.out.println("cookie = " + cookie);
    cookieManager.setCookie(Constants.baseURL, cookie);
}
```

This works fine and if I reload the WebView it seems to have all the right cookies, why am I not logged in in the WebView and does this work in iOS? Do I need to add something else?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have forgotten to use `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(..)`
And call sync on obtained instance

Comment: Isn't CookySyncManager deprecated?

Comment: Yes it is - depends on Version you wan to support - CookieManager starting from API 21 synchronizes automatically.
If it is your case you may try to call `flush()`